# Deleting values from DB (phpmyadmin)

Tags: sql

I have a problem about deleting values from my database. I want to delete values from multiple tables. I have this SQL code:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DELETE uzivatel, inzerat_nabizim, lokalita_nabizim, pronajem_pokoj_nabizim, osoba_nabizim, typ_pokoje_nabizim, vybaveni_pokoj_nabizim, zarizeni_byt_nabizim
                     FROM uzivatel INNER JOIN inzerat_nabizim INNER JOIN lokalita_nabizim INNER JOIN pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     INNER JOIN osoba_nabizim INNER JOIN typ_pokoje_nabizim INNER JOIN vybaveni_pokoj_nabizim INNER JOIN zarizeni_byt_nabizim
                     WHERE uzivatel.id_uzivatel = 1
                     AND inzerat_nabizim.id_uzivatel = uzivatel.id_uzivatel
                     AND pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_inzerat_nabizim = inzerat_nabizim.id_inzerat_nabizim
                     AND osoba_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND typ_pokoje_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND vybaveni_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND zarizeni_byt_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND lokalita_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
```

It's working but badly. This code deletes all of my records (not just that record which id_uzivatel equals to "1"). The only exception is table "uzivatel" - there the code deletes just the record that it's asked for.

Any ideas?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please rewrite your query to use the `on` clause.  The use of `inner join` without an `on` clause looks very awkward, is only supported by MySQL, and is rather confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how. I don't even understand what INNER JOIN does. Does it connect particular tables?

Comment: `inner join` is a basic construct of SQL.  I would suggest that you learn a bit about the language before trying to use it on a real database.

Comment: Its for connecting tables, as I have written.
But I guess this server is for helping people, not telling them what they should or shouldn't learn. And in this case, you're not helping me at all.